# When debugging a package procedure in PL/SQL developer, how do you set a CLOB in parameter value?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm debugging an Oracle package using PL/SQL developer, but I'm running into a problem - one of the parameters is a CLOB (it's a big ass XML string). I can pass it in from the application side and have it be a CLOB, but in the PL/SQL debugger, I put the string representation of the XML into the debugger so the proc in the package treats it as a CLOB? As it stands, when set it, then step into the package, the parameter evaluates to NULL, but the string is fine.

[image: This is the debug setup window]

Comment: Like a charm.  Would have been better than what I ended up doing - having two packages, one for testing and dev where I was justr passing in the string, unclobed, making sure everything worked, and then making those same changes in my package.  Thanks.  I'll use your method in the future.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can always use the pl/sql block that is invoking the SP. In this case deselect the corresponding checkbox to the CLOB parameter, then replace the calling statement with this:

```
declare
    myClob1 clob := to_clob('your data');
begin
    searchtrackingpolicies_split(callerid => :callerid,
                                 xmlcriteria => myClob1,
                                 xmlsearchresults => :xmlsearchresults);
);
end;
```

notice that the colon before myClob1 were removed.

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=18643

Use: 'Temporary CLOB' instead of 'CLOB'
[image]